# State machine cycle with seven segment

Tags: digital-logic

How quickly should that state machine cycle through the digits so that the digits don’t appear to blink?
Need some help with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The persistence of human vision is \$1/16\$ seconds. It means if the frequency is less than \$16\$ Hz, we will it feel like flickering. If your seven segment display array has **n** displays, and time between updation of each of them is **t** seconds, then following condition should satisfy to avoid the feeling of flickering:

$$nt < \frac{1}{16}$$